# Check for the google maps spelling of a location's name

Tags: python, google-maps, selenium

I want to get the travel time between some airports in Europe with google maps. The thing is that some spellings of the names are not accurate, so, I want to first check for wrong names and get google's version of the names. From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972564/python-check-spelling-of-city-names-with-google-maps-api), I am able to use selenium to do that, but my code has some issues, 1) the output is not always complete, (last two result are only one alphabet) 2) it throws an exception at the end of the list (see below). Please help me fix the code. Automating this is the only way as the list of airports is very long.

Input:

```
wronglySpelled = ['Treviso (San Angelo) Airport', 'Milano - Malpensa
       Airport', 'Venezia - Tessera Airport', 'Milano - Linate Airport',
       'Treviso (San Angelo) Airport', 'Treviso (San Angelo) Airport',
      'Milano - Malpensa Airport', 'Venezia - Tessera Airport', 'Guernsey
       Channel Is. Airport', 'Jersey Channel Is. Airport','Treviso (San
                     Angelo) Airport']
```

Code:

```
def setup():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("http://maps.google.com")
    driver.maximize_window() # For maximizing window
    driver.implicitly_wait(20) # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds
    return driver

def correct_name(driver, name_to_check):
    searchBox = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    searchBox.send_keys(name_to_check)
    correct_name = driver.find_element_by_class_name('suggest-bold')
    return correct_name.text.encode('utf-8')

driver = setup()
for item in wronglySpelled:
    print item,':', correct_name(driver, item)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_id('searchboxinput').clear()
driver.quit()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/...", line 60, in <module>
    print item,':', correct_name(driver, item)
  File "C:/...", line 41, in correct_name
    correct_name = driver.find_element_by_class_name('suggest-bold')
  File "C:\...", line 415, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\...", line 756, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\...", line 238, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\...", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"suggest-bold"}
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

output:

```
## Formatted as Input name : Google maps version
Treviso (San Angelo) Airport : Aeroporto di Treviso Canova
Milano - Malpensa Airport : Milano Malpensa Airport
Venezia - Tessera Airport : Venice Marco Polo Airport
Milano - Linate Airport : Aeroporto Milano Linate
Treviso (San Angelo) Airport : Aeroporto di Treviso Canova
Treviso (San Angelo) Airport : Aeroporto di Treviso Canova
Milano - Malpensa Airport : m
Venezia - Tessera Airport : V
Guernsey Channel Is. Airport :
```

Comment: You should use the google maps api. It should be infinitely faster, etc.

Comment: When your script types `Guernsey Channel Is. Airport` into the field, Google has no suggestions for it. As a result, there is never an element in the DOM with a class name of `suggest-bold`, which in turn throws the `NoSuchElementException` you are seeing.

Comment: @LeviNoecker any explanation for the `Milano - Malpensa Airport` that returns `m`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JeffC mentioned in his comment, you'd probably be better off using the Google Maps API to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do.

A couple things from your script:

- I find implicit waits to be mostly worthless. It is worth the time, in my opinion, to learn about explicit waits, how they work, and when they are useful. Because Google tends use highly dynamic websites which AJAX in a lot of their information, things like Maps tend to work best if you use explicit waits.
- Your script was throwing the `NoSuchElementException` because Google had no suggestions for that term, so your search term, `suggest-bold` never matched anything. Typically when I see a NSEE that is a red flag that I need to re-evaluate how I'm searching
- I think, but I am not positive, that the `Milano - Malpensa Airport : m` output is a result of the selenium collecting the text from the element before the element has fully loaded.
- I personally avoid hard sleeps (`time.sleep(5)`) at all costs, as they can easily cause your scripts to break if you experience any network lag. This is another area where explicit waits shine, as they can try and try and try to find an element until it is actually loaded, and then move on.

That said, here is how I would do it:

```
from explicit import waiter, ID
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

NO_SUGGESTION = 'Add a missing place to Google Maps.'

original_names = [
    'Treviso (San Angelo) Airport',
    'Milano - Malpensa Airport',
    'Venezia - Tessera Airport',
    'Milano - Linate Airport',
    'Treviso (San Angelo) Airport',
    'Treviso (San Angelo) Airport',
    'Milano - Malpensa Airport',
    'Venezia - Tessera Airport',
    'Guernsey Channel Is. Airport',
    'Jersey Channel Is. Airport',
    'Treviso (San Angelo) Airport'
]


def get_name_suggestion(driver, name):
    # Find the search box, clear it, write the name
    waiter.find_write(driver, 'searchboxinput', name, by=ID, clear_first=True)

    class SuggestionLoads(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self._last_seen = None

        def __call__(self, driver):
            """ Custom expected condition.
                Returns either the first suggested name, or '<No Suggestion>'
                Raises a TimeoutException in the event the page source is different
            """
            suggestion_icon = 'div.suggest-icon-container'
            suggest_css = 'div.suggest-left-cell > span.suggest-query'
            try:

                # Only want suggestions that have the location icon next to them, and not the
                # magnifying glass. Return False if we don't find any so as to retry
                icons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(suggestion_icon)
                if len(icons) < 1:
                    return False

                elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(suggest_css)

                if len(elems) == 0:
                    # No suggestions have loaded yet, return False so the Wait can retry
                    return False

                suggest_text = elems[0].text
                if len(suggest_text) == 1:
                    # Sometimes we catch text mid-update. Return False to retry
                    # and hopefully get the whole suggestion
                    return False
                elif suggest_text == NO_SUGGESTION:
                    # Google has no suggestion for us, return NO_SUGGESTION, which the Wait will
                    # evaluate as True and exit
                    return '<No Suggestion>'
                else:
                    # We found a valid suggestion. We need to make sure nothing else is going to
                    # get AJAXed in, so compare it to or _last_seen property. If they match,
                    # everything has stabilized and return the string, which will be evaluated as
                    # True and cause the Wait to exit
                    # If you don't do this, you wind up with jung suggestions like "Traffic"
                    if suggest_text == self._last_seen:
                        return suggest_text
                    else:
                        self._last_seen = suggest_text
                        return False

            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                # Because the DOM is constantly updating, there is a pretty decent chance that a
                # SERE will get thrown. Catch it if it does and return False so the Wait
                # can try again
                return False

    return Wait(driver, 30).until(SuggestionLoads())


def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    try:
        driver.get("http://maps.google.com")
        driver.maximize_window()
        for orig_name in original_names:
            suggested_name = get_name_suggestion(driver, orig_name)
            print "{0}: {1}".format(orig_name, suggested_name)
    finally:  # This is useful to make sure the browsers get closed, even if an exception is thrown
        driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Which returns:

```
 (.venv27) ➜  tmp python google_maps.py
 Treviso (San Angelo) Airport: Aeroporto di Treviso Canova
 Milano - Malpensa Airport: Milano Malpensa Airport
 Venezia - Tessera Airport: Venice Marco Polo Airport
 Milano - Linate Airport: Aeroporto Milano Linate
 Treviso (San Angelo) Airport: Aeroporto di Treviso Canova
 Treviso (San Angelo) Airport: Aeroporto di Treviso Canova
 Milano - Malpensa Airport: Milano Malpensa Airport
 Venezia - Tessera Airport: Venice Marco Polo Airport
 Guernsey Channel Is. Airport: <No Suggestion>
 Jersey Channel Is. Airport: <No Suggestion>
 Treviso (San Angelo) Airport: Aeroporto di Treviso Canova
```

Full discloser: `explicit` is a library I maintain and is available from PyPI: `pip install explicit`. It's designed to make using explicit waits easier, but you could replace it with a garden variety Wait

Comment: thank you for your detailed analysis of my code and your solution. This works very well.